# How to create a message which have generic type as field?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I am using protobuf for my project. If its possible to create a **message** that have something like this.

```
message GenericType{
    T value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `google.protobuf.Any` type for serialization, but you have to be aware that each application who works with your data should to know how to pack/unpack these messages.